# Assigning proper lifetimes to associated types

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am designing code that should be generic over a trait `Atom`, that contains many associated types that logically belong together. In the simplified example below, which concerns representing a mathematical expression, there is one variant that gives a 'view' of a `Pow` and an owned version of a `Pow`. In actuality, there will be many more variants, such as `Var` and `OwnedVar`, `Function` and `OwnedFunction`, etc.

Since some traits deal with borrowed data, I added lifetimes and this makes the code below not compile:

```rust
pub trait Atom {
    // imagine more variants here
    type P<'a>: Pow<'a, R = Self>;
    type OP: OwnedPow<R = Self>;
}

pub trait Pow<'a> {
    type R: Atom;
    fn get_base(&self) -> AtomView<Self::R>;
}

pub trait OwnedPow {
    type R: Atom;
    fn to_view<'a>(&'a self) -> AtomView<Self::R>;
}

pub enum AtomView<'a, R: Atom> {
    Pow(R::P<'a>),
}

impl<'a, R: Atom> AtomView<'a, R> {
    #[allow(unconditional_recursion, irrefutable_let_patterns)]
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        if let AtomView::Pow(p2) = other {
            let b = p2.get_base();
            Some(self.partial_cmp(&b).unwrap())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

// concrete implementations

struct Rep;

impl Atom for Rep {
    type P<'a> = PowD<'a>;
    type OP = OwnedPowD;
}

struct PowD<'a> {
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Pow<'a> for PowD<'a> {
    type R = Rep;

    fn get_base(&self) -> AtomView<Self::R> {
        AtomView::Pow(PowD {
            data: &self.data[1..],
        })
    }
}

struct OwnedPowD {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl OwnedPow for OwnedPowD {
    type R = Rep;

    fn to_view<'a>(&'a self) -> AtomView<Rep> {
        AtomView::Pow(PowD { data: &self.data })
    }
}

fn test<A: OwnedPow>(a: A) {
    let _vv = a.to_view();
}

fn main() {
    let v = OwnedPowD {
        data: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    test(v);
}
```

This code does not compile:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `other`
  --> src/main.rs:25:21
   |
23 |     fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
   |                                  ----- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `other`: `&'a AtomView<'a, R>`
24 |         if let AtomView::Pow(p2) = other {
25 |             let b = p2.get_base();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'a` required
```

Of course, giving `other` the lifetime `a` is a problem, since `other` is a locally created variable and thus following the help will not fix the problem. I fail to see why `&b` seems to have the lifetime `&'a b`.

The code can be tested on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3da2cc1cd778c068f87bc7062be67f21).

I tried fixing this code by dropping many lifetimes in the associated types and traits, but then it seems I need to give `Rep` a lifetime, and then this `Rep<'a>` will make its way into `OwnedPowD` that should have no lifetime (since the data is owned). This attempt can be tried [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66f79146d97d983889aa64280b520ee4).

Does anyone know how to assign proper lifetimes?

Comment: It could be that my lifetimes are wrong altogether, because I misunderstood when they should be added. I think the easiest way to understand what I am trying to do is looking at `PowD`, and `OwnedPowD`. These are implementations of the traits `Pow` and `OwnedPow`. Since `PowD` has a lifetime since it is a reference to a slice (possible created using `to_view`), I figured I should put this lifetime in the trait `Pow` as well, signalling that `Pow`s are always borrowed. In my second attempt I dropped the lifetimes, but then I struggle to make `OwnedPow` lifetime free.

Comment: The compiler hint is telling you to try `fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &'a AtomView<'a, R>)`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AtomView` has a lifetime argument, which should connect all of the borrowing dependencies together. But you are never specifying it!

```
pub enum AtomView<'a, R: Atom> {
    Pow(R::P<'a>),
}
```

I was able to [make your code compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e18bff07b27feaadd1cf1e19a1fb6cbd) by changing the trait methods to constrain this lifetime in the "obvious" way in each case:

```
pub trait Pow<'a> {
    type R: Atom;
    fn get_base(&self) -> AtomView<'a, Self::R>;
}

pub trait OwnedPow {
    type R: Atom;
    fn to_view(&self) -> AtomView<'_, Self::R>;
}
```

And updating the implementations to match:

```
impl<'a> Pow<'a> for PowD<'a> {
    type R = Rep;

    fn get_base(&self) -> AtomView<'a, Self::R> {
        // just for testing
        AtomView::Pow(PowD {
            data: &self.data[1..],
        })
    }
}

impl OwnedPow for OwnedPowD {
    type R = Rep;

    fn to_view(&self) -> AtomView<'_, Rep> {
        AtomView::Pow(PowD { data: &self.data })
    }
}
```